# Flattening an array of matrices to a single matrix (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flatten

I have a list of matrices:

```
arr = [array([[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]), array([[4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 1]])]
```

I want to flatten them in the following way:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 1]]
```

`numpy.flatten` flattens it into a single array of numbers.
I tried this: `flattened_list = [y for x in arr for y in x]`
It does the job, but all rows of the matrix are numpy arrays.
Is there any way to flatten numpy arrays upto a certain depth?

Comment: `np.reshape(arr,(-1,max([a.shape[-1] for a in arr])))` or `np.concatenate(arr)`?

Comment: @Divakar Wonderful! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use reshape:

```
out = arr.reshape((4,3))
```

Comment: `arr` is a list and does not have a reshape method.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) function from numpy. It takes a tuple of ndarrays and returns a new ndarray which is the result of stacking them vertically with the first ndarray being on top and so on.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([1, 2])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4])
>>> c = np.array([5, 6])
>>> np.vstack(a, b)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

In your case you can easily call the `tuple` function on your list of ndarrays

```
>>> arr = [array([[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]), array([[4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 1]])]
>>> np.vstack(tuple(arr))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

If you want your answer as a python list then just call  numpy's `ndarray.tolist` function on the result like so:

```
>>> np.ndarray.tolist(np.vstack(arr))
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 1]]
```